# Modal Dialog appears autommatically before I click the image

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app I have this problem: why when I run my app the Modal appears before I click on images?

In other words after click on `Run App` button the modal appears. But after this everything works well. The only problem is when I start the app

How can I adjust this?

I tried using `isolate()` function but didn't work

Any help?

this is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  1:20%>%
    map( ~
           div(
             class = 'item',
             
             p('Paragraph',
               class = 'one two',
               style = ''),
             tags$a(
               id = paste0(.x),
               href = "#",class = "action-button",
               tags$img(src = 'logo.png',
                        style = 'object-fit: cover; object-position: center; 
                                 height: 100%;width: 100%;')) 
             
           )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  toListen <- reactive({
    
    
    
    1:20 %>% map(
      ~ input[[paste0(.x)]]
    )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(toListen(),{
    showModal(modalDialog(size = "l",
                          h1('Modal')))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply set `ignoreInit = TRUE` in `observeEvent` to prevent the initial execution:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  1:20%>%
    map( ~
           div(
             class = 'item',
             
             p('Paragraph',
               class = 'one two',
               style = ''),
             tags$a(
               id = paste0(.x),
               href = "#",class = "action-button",
               tags$img(src = 'logo.png',
                        style = 'object-fit: cover; object-position: center; 
                                 height: 100%;width: 100%;')) 
             
           )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  toListen <- reactive({
    
    
    
    1:20 %>% map(
      ~ input[[paste0(.x)]]
    )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(toListen(),{
    showModal(modalDialog(size = "l",
                          h1('Modal')))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @ismirsehregel thanks for yout time. Humm, whats the idea? The modal should be displayed once I trigger the `toListen()`. Using `ignoreInit` considers only the "second" trigger?

Comment: @JohnBonesJohnBones, please see the help `?observeEvent`: *ignoreInit:
If TRUE, then, when this observeEvent is first created/initialized, ignore the handlerExpr (the second argument), whether it is otherwise supposed to run or not. The default is FALSE. See Details.*